# How to clear drawings on View but preserve background color?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-custom-view

I have a CustomView. In the overridden `onDraw(...)` method of that `View` I draw certain things using the provided `Canvas` object.

Upon refreshing the View, I want to **remove all drawings** on the `Canvas` that have been done previously. For that, I call

```
Canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
```

everytime before redrawing the `View` and everything previously drawn is gone. So far so good.

The problem is if I specify a background color for that `View` in **.xml** (let's say gray), the `View's` background will still be white since I always "overlay" the background color with white upon refreshing the `View`.

How can I resolve that issue and clear the canvas with preserving the background color?

I have tried calling

```
Canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Unfortunately, then the background turns black.

Answer (score 0):

how about using layer list to set the background at the back and the image at the front. Once the view is refreshed, load the list with the image remove, only showing the background in the view

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but the solution maybe to use `view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` and use `view.getDrawingCache()`...